# nginx nested upstream

Tags: nginx

this is my current upstream definition

```
upstream mybackend {
  server cache-server;
  server app-server-1 backup;
  server app-server-2 backup;
}
```

Every request goes to cache-server and when it's down the requests will go to app-server-1 without balancing between app-server-1 and -2.

Is it possible to do something like this?

```
upstream mybackend {
  server cache-server;
  server app-server-cluster backup;
}

upstream app-server-cluster{
  server app-server-1;
  server app-server-2;
}
```

... when cache-server goes down nginx will take the app-server-cluster and will balance between 1 and 2?

Answer (score 2):

No, nesting in such a way is not currently supported.  The documentation at http://nginx.org/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#server is pretty clear in what kind of parameters the `server` directive accepts.

On the other hand, are you certain that in the existing configuration `nginx` would not be balancing the load between appserver-1 and -2, if you specify both as `backup`?  Documentation is not specific of what behaviour is to be expected in a situation like this; I would argue that specifying two `backup` servers should make `nginx` balance the requests between all such backup servers; if that's not the case, but you need it to be, then perhaps you should log an RfE: http://nginx.org/en/support.html.

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can just create a separate "server config" for your app-server-XX on some other ports in the same nginx.conf and configure it as you want. Then you can use it in your "mybackend" upstream exactly as you told before.